# ReSharper's "Coverage Tree" is empty?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, code-coverage

I'm using VS2012 Pro with ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2.  When I tell ReSharper to "Cover All Tests from Solution" (via the ReSharper menu's Unit Tests menu), the unit tests all run, and it shows me whether they passed or failed, and then after a second or two more, the "Coverage Analysis in Progress" message goes away.  This is all as I would expect so far, but at the end of it, the coverage tree is left with this:

[image: blank coverage tree]

Whereas I'm used to it showing the percentage covered of the modules and such; more along the lines of this picture from their website:

[image: sample coverage tree]

It's like ReSharper doesn't understand what code was invoked during the tests, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I found something on the web indicating that it's a problem with ReSharper 10.0.2, which suggested disabling the option "Shadow-copy assemblies being tested" (from "ReSharper/Options/Tools/Unit Testing").  Doing so seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing these are xunit tests? There was an issue with the plugin for 10.0.2 that caused this. It's been fixed for 2016.1 (previously known as 10.1), which has xunit in the box. You don't need to disable shadow copy here.

Comment: @citizenmatt, yes, they're written with xUnit.net.  Is the "2016.1" you refer to not yet released, or something like that? When I tell my ReSharper 10.0.2 to check for updates, it says everything's up to date.  Plus, when I download the installer from JetBrain's website, it's called "JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.10.0.2.exe".

Comment: Good point! It's not released yet, but it's due any minute now. You can download an EAP preview build, but I wouldn't bother and just hang on for the release, it won't be long.

Comment: And it's released - feel free to download now.